# how to add all the integers between two lines with a pattern and print

Tags: command-line, unix, shell, script

I have an input file (sample.txt)

```
Sat 02/28/2015__19:32:37.63 
   262,404 K
   100,964 K
   112,052 K
   124,628 K
Sat 02/28/2015__19:37:38.41 
   262,408 K
   100,964 K
   112,056 K
Sun 02/29/2015__16:32:40.11 
   262,443 K
   100,964 K
   112,052 K
   124,628 K
Sun 02/29/2015__16:32:49.20 
   262,408 K
   100,964 K
   112,022 K
```

I want to print the line with patterns Sat and Sun and then (sum of all the numbers between the two patterns).
I want to output something like below

```
Sat 02/28/2015__19:32:37.63 
600048 
Sat 02/28/2015__19:37:38.41
475463
Sun 02/29/2015__16:32:40.11
600087
Sun 02/29/2015__16:32:49.20 
475394
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>1 && /^[SMTWF]/{print sum;f=0} /^S/{print;sum=0;f=1;next} {sum+=$1$2} END{if (f)print sum}' file
Sat 02/28/2015__19:32:37.63 
600048
Sat 02/28/2015__19:37:38.41 
475428
Sun 02/29/2015__16:32:40.11 
600087
Sun 02/29/2015__16:32:49.20 
475394
```

#### How it works

- `-F,`

  Use a comma for the field separator.
- `NR>1 && /^[SMTWF]/{print sum;f=0}`

  For any line after the first, if it starts with the first letter of a day of the week, then print the sum.
- `/^S/{print;sum=0;f=1;next}`

  If the current line starts with the letter S (for Saturday or Sunday), then print the line, initialize the sum to 0, set the flag `f` to 1, and skip directly to the `next` line.
- `sum+=$1$2`

  For all other lines, add the number to `sum`.  `awk` would not understand a comma separating the digits.  Since a comma was used as the field separator, then `$1$2` is the number without the comma which is a form that awk will understand.
- `END{if (f)print sum}`

  Print the last remaining sum if we are currently on a Saturday or Sunday group.  To accomplish this, we use the flag `f`.  If the last grouping was Monday through Friday, then f==0 and the sum won't print.  If it was Saturday or Sunday, then f==1 and it will print.